# Manage jwt from nodejs on front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have an aplication which is using jwt authentication, so i have an api `/login`, where i generate jwt like:

```
res.cookie('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token, {httOnly: true});
```

When i login in on front end, in react js, the server generate jwt token.
Questions:

How to manage jwt on front end, after log in? (now the token is sent in cookie and i can't read it using javascript), and when i go to another route after login, i have to send back from front end the token, but it is only on `/login` page not in second route. I now that i can handle token using localStorage, but this s not secure. So, how, in my situation to send back the token if i navigate after login on another page?

Comment: the best thing to do is save the jwt on localstorage after login and save only public data that has no harm if someone gets and send that in auth header in every request to authenticate user and expire the token after some time

Comment: What makes you assume that localstorage is not secure?

Comment: Is your login page on a different domain than your application? Otherwise the cookie should be sent with every request just fine, without any extra effort by the frontend code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't switch domains, and the cookie path is global, then you can access it from any page in the front-end. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Also, I would think twice before going with cookies. I would suggest using short-lived tokens (30 mins) with `refreshTokens` (30 mins) in `localStorage` and send them using the standard `Authorization` header, and not having to worry about someone stealing them. (Just don't store sensitive data in there). The refresh token will periodically require a new pair of token/refresh, before the time runs out.

There is also `sessionStorage` if you wouldn't like to persist the data for a long time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage with the trick that, each tab/window has separate `sessionStorage`.